# I can add multiple documents inspite having same values while having necessary validations(in schema unique is set to true)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

> connection.js where mongodb is connecting to express

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex",true);

let userSchema = {
    "username":{
        type:String,
        required:[true,'Required Field'],
        unique:true
    },
    "password":{
        type:String,
        required:[true,'Required Field'],
        unique:true

    },
    "emailId":{
        type:String,
        required:[true,'Required Field'],
        unique:true
    }
}

let accountSchema = new Schema(userSchema,{collection:"Account",timestamps:true});
let connection = {}
connection.getAccountsCollection = () =>{
    return mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/BLOGSDB",{useNewUrlParser:true})
    .then((db)=>{
        return db.model('Account',accountSchema)
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err.message);
        let error = new Error("Could not connect to database");
        error.status = 500;
        throw error;
    })
}
module.exports = connection;
```

> model.js Doing a create object request

```
const connection = require('../utilities/connection');
const userDb = {}
userDb.addUser = (userObj) =>{
    console.log('addUser here',userObj);
    return connection.getAccountsCollection().then((model)=>{
        return model.create(userObj).then((insertedData)=>{
            console.log('Add account called')
            if(insertedData){
                return insertedData
            }
            else{
                console.log('error occured');
                let err = new Error('Data not inserted');
                err.status = 500;
                throw err;
            }
        })
    })
}

module.exports = userDb;
```

> Unique:true is not working here , code is showing no error while putting multiple documents at once.connection.js file is for connecting to mongodb and model js is connected to connection.js, inserting documents is shwoing no error while adding identical documents

Comment: Does the database show these duplicate documents afterward?

Answer (score 0):

No, If you are using validation unique set to True You can't have same values.